# is there is a way to print the database query result using SQLConnection

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I am creating a `SQLConnection` to access some data. I need to print the entire DB result in log

I can able to print the specific cell value by referring out the cell, but I want to print the query result at single shot

```
string queryString = "select top 1 column_1, column_2 from master_table";
using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(envDBConnectionString))
{
     SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, dbConnection);
     dbConnection.Open();
     SqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
     if (dbReader.HasRows)
     {
    while (dbReader.Read())
    {
            string col1Value = dbReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
            string col2Value = dbReader.GetValue(1).ToString());
         }
    }
    dbReader.Close();
    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

Here I am getting each column value and stores it to string variable. instead I want to store the entire query result in that string

Comment: Do you mean you want to put the result into a some sort of a collection i.e. `DataTable`?

Comment: I want to display the results in log(Either as table or DB results in XML style). Now I using like ```args.Activity.Report("Query Result", "<Column1>" + col1Value + "</Column1><Column2>" + col2Value + "</Column2>");```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *method extracting*, i.e.

```
// Given a query, return records
private static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> QueryLines(string query) {
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(envDBConnectionString)) {
    con.Open();

    using (var q = new SqlCommand(query, con)) {
      using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read())
          yield return reader as IDataRecord;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then we can easily use it:

```
string command = 
  @"select top 1 
           column_1 as Column1, 
           column_2 as Column2
      from master_table";
```

Having records, write them into a log in a desired format, e.g. simple CSV

```
File.AppendAllLines(@"c:\MyLog.txt", QueryLines(command)
  .Select(record => $"{record[0]},{record[1]}"));
```

Or in elaborated XML

```
File.AppendAllLines(@"c:\MyLog.txt", QueryLines(command)
  .Select(record => string.Concat(Enumerable
    .Range(0, record.FieldCount)
    .Select(i => $"<{record.GetName(i)}>{record[i]}</{record.GetName(i)}>")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string queryString = "select top 1 column_1, column_2 from master_table";
using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(envDBConnectionString))
{
     SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, dbConnection);
     SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //All your data in this datatable
     sa.fill(dt);
}
```

for reference:
**Inside loop:**

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.rows){
   row["COLUMN_NAME"].toString(); //or whatever datatype
}
```